(Sufficiently) Rigorous argument for Planck scale and formation of black holes
I used to hear the arguments about how if we go down to Planck scale (see, e.g., this lecture notes that I am reading but by no means the only place I saw this) then "you would need energies of order the Planck mass $\hbar/l_{pl}$, at which point you would start to make black holes". Maybe it is because my general relativity (GR) background is rusty, but when I think about it now I found it difficult to make sense of it.
There are several reasons, but maybe two issues I have are the following:

This argument, at least in the above spirit, sounds very non-covariant. Energy is an observer-dependent quantity, so statements about $E\sim \mathcal{O}(\hbar/l_{pl})$ seems meaningless without further qualification. Energy density does not help either, since the component of the stress-energy tensor $T_{00}$ is its own is still observer-dependent.

Taking the example of Schwarzschild black hole solution, the metric is only a function of mass $M$ and not mass density. It seems that what matters more is total (ADM) mass. Of course this cannot be the full story, since if the mass is distributed extremely sparsely around the universe you do not get a black hole. So clearly some form of density argument should apply. Then again, known exact solutions of a star collapse does not seem to relate to Planck length argument (or at least I don't see why).


The closest I have seen is the paper by Christodoulou here which is too much for my current paygrade. But reading the preface, it seems that the formation of black holes uses some form of density argument, but this time (if I did the dimensional analysis correctly) is more like "power per solid angle" being larger than some fixed constant defined in a natural coordinates (Eddington-Finkelstein-type?).
Question: is there a good and sufficiently simple way to make the "resolving the Planck scale leads to formation of a black hole" more precise, e.g., by connecting to Christodoulou's results or something else? Or is this something obvious that somehow I could not see?
Remark: all I am asking for is a sufficiently rigorous and precise connection, without delving into the functional analytic bits (unless we really have to), at most around the same level of exposition of Wald's textbook. Also, as far as I can tell this argument is purely classical and so I don't expect anything from quantum electrodynamics (QED) or quantum gravity (QG) to play a role. If QED or QG are absolutely necessary to make this precise, then I would like to see that laid out (preferably not with this sort of $\sim$ type argument, if possible).

Rigorous argument isn't reliable in physics without confirmation from experiment. You can't have mathematical rigor without unquestioned axioms, and we have none of those. We also have no experiments applicable to this question.

Have a look at Assaf Shomer, “A pedagogical explanation for the non-renormalizability of gravity” arXiv:0709.3555.

@A.V.S. The beginning of the last chapter assumes that black holes dominate the high energy spectrum of GR and describes the static multidimensional Schwarzschild solution. So the argument in this paper seems reversed. Black holes at high energy are assumed in the static case. It doesn’t look like the paper addressed this question on resolving the Planck scale by ultra relativistic particles.

To resolve the Planck scsle with a particle accelerator, you need a high energy particle. From the uncertainty principle, you need to convert the mass of 2,000 galaxies of the Virgo cluster to the energy of one particle. Neglecting unrealistic technical challenges, this particle itself doesn’t form a black hole. When this particle hits a target and is deflected without losing enough energy to form a black hole in the target, then no black hole is formed while resolving the Planck scale.
